# sending output of linux command into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, linux, csv

i have the following linux command:

```
os.system('cat *' + FILENAME + '*comp_value/' + VARINLASTLINE + '.csv | grep -v SOMETHING | sort -u > test.csv')
```

As can be seen, I first cat some csv files, grep to eliminate the last line, and then use sort to create a test.csv file.
However I will be doing this for a large list of large files and I do not want to create dummy test.csv files every time I cat the files together. Is there a way to output the cat of these files directly into the pandas dataframe instead of creating a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.popen`:

```py
cmd = 'cat *' + FILENAME + '*comp_value/' + VARINLASTLINE + '.csv | grep -v SOMETHING | sort -u > test.csv'

pipe = os.popen(cmd)
df = pandas.read_csv(pipe)
```